# Best practice when getting values in Google Sheets script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script to make a copy of a sheet and paste some data into the sheet. I have to make C. 500 copies of the sheet hence why I'm trying to improve my code and learn something along the way.

Below is the code pulling the data from named ranges in my sheet, all of this data is then used somewhere else in my script.

My question is - is there a better/ more efficient way of getting all the data and managing it? All columns are side by side so I could get all the information in a single variable with just one call to the sheet but it would be difficult to manage the arrays further down the code using [0], [1] references etc.

```
var getTeachersNameReq = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!teachersNameReq').getValues().filter(String); //Logger.log(getTeachersNameReq);
var getTeachersEmailReq = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!teachersEmailReq').getValues().filter(String); //Logger.log(getTeacherEmailReq);
var getTeachersNameOpt = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!teachersNameOpt').getValues().filter(String); //Logger.log(getTeachersNameOpt);
var getTeachersEmailOpt = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!teachersEmailOpt').getValues().filter(String); //Logger.log(getTeachersNameOpt);
var getSubjectGroup = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!subjectGroup').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getSubjectGroup);  
var getSubjectCode = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!subjectCode').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getSubjectCode);
var getSubjectName = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!subjectName').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getSubjectName);
var getCoTeacher = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!coTeacher').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getCoTeacher);  
var getNewFileNames = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!ERBFileName').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getNewFileNames);  
var getERBexists =  ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!ERBExists').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getERBexists);
var getCanTeacherEdit =  ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!teacherCanEdit').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getCanTeacherEdit);
var getClass = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!class').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getClass);
var getOBECExamSheet = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!OBECExamSheet').getValues().slice(0, getTeachersNameReq.length); //Logger.log(getOBECExamSheet);
var getSemester = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!semester').getValue(); //Logger.log(getSemester);
var getAcedimicYear = ss.getRangeByName('ERB Generator!acedimicYear').getValue(); //Logger.log(getAcedimicYear);  
var getNameListFileID = ss.getRangeByName('File Links Data!nameListFileID').getValues().toString(); //Logger.log(getNameListFileID);
```

Comment: 16 calls to getValues() is not a problem, considering you also have different logic for different columns. It's generally advised not to do separate getValue calls for retrieving entries from a homogeneous array of data, but what you are doing is different.

Comment: Yes, it still only takes a few milliseconds to get all the data so it's very little in the overall scope of the script. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Please add details about the criteria to qualify an alternative as better or more efficient.

Comment: I don't have the criteria to qualify that hence why I came here, this is not a test, this is a question. Different people will have a different definition of 'better' and 'more efficient' in respect to my question.

Answer (score 0):

`getValues()` slows down your script.

I usually make only one read from the sheet:

1. Sheets: Prepare all the data in single list
2. Sheets: Joining it in single cell
3. Script: getValue() of the cell (getting string)
4. Script: Parsing the string

### **Step1. Prepare all the data in single list**

Some data is just a value. I use JSON for parsing it:

- string -- put in double quotes: `"srtring"`
- numbers -- leave as it is: `500`

If I need an array, I join it with semicolon `;` and put into double quotes `""`

- array: `"one,two,three,4,5,6"`

### **Step2. Joining it in single cell**

put it into brackets: `[]` and divide by comma `,`:

- `["srtring",500,"one,two,three,4,5,6"]`

### **Step3. getValue() of the cell**

I usually make the same named range, so I don't need to change the code:

```
var strData = ss.getRangeByName('eval').getValue();
```

### **Step4. Parsing the string**

To get the data as an array, I use this function:

```
var data = JSON.parse(strData);
```

Strings and numbers are ready to be used in script, arrays are splitted:

```
var array = data[2].split(';');
```

---

I also suggest reading data when the file is opening `onOpen` and use [properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to hold the variables.

Comment: Ok, yes, I see the benefit of doing that. However, if 'eval' is more that one cell you still need to call .getValues(). I will test out your suggestion of merging the data to a single cell and doing as you suggest. Thanks for your input.